# I can't create bundle in symfony2

Tags: php, windows

I have Windows 7 and [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) localhost on drive `D:`. I installed Symfony2 correctly. When I open `http://127.0.0.1/Symfony/web/config.php` I can see the Welcome! message. But in the tutorial "Creating Pages in Symfony2" when I want to create a bundle by this command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

This message appears:

```
"php is not recognized as an internal or external command oprable program or batch file"
```

I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving that error because PHP is not in your system `PATH`. Check out [this quick tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/) on installing PHP on Windows. Take note of **Step 4** which is the installation step that should fix your problem.

Since you're using WampServer, the path you have to add to `PATH` will be something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wamp\bin\php5.3.10"
```

This is only an example, change the path to the actual path to PHP on your system. If the path has spaces in it (like `Program Files (x86)` does) it is helpful to always surround it with quotes (").

---

**Update:** I ended up getting on a screen sharing program with @reza and discovered he had accidentally set his `PATH` variable to `D:\php\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.exe` rather than `D:\php\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10`. Fixing this solved the problem.

Comment: I do all of top task but when i run this command php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml this message appears "could not open input file:app/console" i set full control permission for app folder

Comment: I would seem that the path to `php.exe` is still **not** in your path. Try this: get the path to `php.exe` (e.g. `C:\php\php.exe`) and use it to run the console: `"C:\php\php.exe" app/console list` - does this work? After editing your `PATH` variable, you must close/re-open the command window for it to refresh with your updated environment variables. Check that you have the right path by running this: `echo %PATH%`

Comment: my php folder path is "D:\php\wamp\bin\php"

Comment: my php folder path is "D:\php\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10" i add php.exe to that then i try "D:\php\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10  app/console list" but i see this message again "could not open input file:app/console"