# PHP app\console wont work trying to create bundle for Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, iis-7

I have installed Symfony2 on a iis 7 server with PHP 5.3.21 and everything works ok ( the php, the symphony demo page ).

I try to create my own helloWorld, as the tutorial says :

php app/console generate:bundle

I go Start->Run->CMD and put that line of code and it gives me back this :

could not open input file : app/console
and before anyone asks i am in the project directory when i perform this command

I put the PHP directory to the System PATH but the problem persists.

Comment: So you are 100% sure that you are doing all correct ,  here is same question with step by step sample maybe  this could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045352/php-app-console-wont-work-trying-to-create-bundle-for-symphony2

Comment: im absolutely certain i have done all this hence why im asking the same question

Comment: does your user account have permissions to execute/read the app/console file?

Comment: Yes it does have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ended up getting on a screen sharing program with @reza and discovered he had accidentally set his PATH variable to D:\php\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.exe rather than D:\php\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10. Fixing this solved the problem.

Check this: [I can't create bundle in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657223/i-cant-create-bundle-in-symfony2)

Comment: I've tried this and I get the same message and sometimes no output from the dos prompt

Comment: i have tried all and i cant seem to figure out what is the problem everything is configure in the path ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES. i suspect that its something to do with the installation of the framework

Comment: i suspect i may have to configure iis7 to use symfony2 feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Symfony (2.4.x or newer) use this method on windows to resolve the problem:

1. Go to project directory e.g. d:/xampp/symfony2-project/ and open composer.json and place this under requires array `"symfony/console": "2.4.*@dev"`. And save the file.
2. Open command-line and cd to project's directory.
3. Use this command to let download and install the dependencies: `php path/to/composer.phar install`. Remember you should be in your project's directory and path/to/composer.phar is the actual path to your composer.phar file.
4. Now you are all done, just use `php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=Test/PrintBundle --format=yml` to test bundle system works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating Symfony 2.5 project using command prompt then console file is not storing the app folder but it storing in the bin folder so you need to use bin folder instead of app folder (CODE is : php bin/console generate:bundle).